# backwards selection of glm does not change the complete model

Tags: r, output, glm, anova, interpretation

I am very new to working with GLM. I have a dataset with categorical (as factors) and numerical predictor variables and the response variable is count data wiht a poisson distribution. These I put in a glm:

`glm2<- glm(formula = count ~ Salinity + Period + Intensity + Depth + Temp + Treatment, data = dfglm, family = "poisson")`

Treatment(1.1 - 3.6) and Period (morning/midday) are factors.

The output looks like this:

[image: output glm]

I already see multiple suprising things in this output (very big difference between the null-deviance and residual deviance, treatment 1.1 not showing, period morning and midday not shown as separate levels, very high standard errors) but I will continue for now.

For the backward selection I used this code:

```
        backward<-step(glm2,direction="backward",trace=0)
        summary(backward)
```

I got exactly the same output as given above. Also when checking `backward$coefficients`, all coefficients remained.

Lastly I tried this:

[image]

If anyone could give me advice/an interpretation of this output and how to make a better model with a working backward selection, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1. Please don't use stepwise selection, see [this paper](https://eprints.ncl.ac.uk/file_store/production/56364/AE9762E1-23E2-4C9D-9518-5BCDAD47FAAB.pdf) or [this stackexchange post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259967/understanding-why-stepwise-selecton-based-on-p-values-is-bad) why it's not a good idea. What is your goal with the model?

Comment: 2. You don't see the first category of factor variables as own variables because they are contained in the intercept, see [e.g. this post](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/40-regression-analysis/163-regression-with-categorical-variables-dummy-coding-essentials-in-r/)

Comment: My goal is to determine what predictors are important determinants of the response variable, as I suspect that some of my predictors might not be very influential.
Also, my supervisor wants me to work with glm backward selection, but I could propose a convincing alternative...

Interesting did not know of this critique on stepwise selection. Mine would not be based on p-values but AIC. Are there other methods you suggest to create a better GLM.